# What does 'exist beyond' mean in the passage?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean 'such reactions exist ***in addition to*** any tendencies'?
Or, such reactions ***precede*** any tendencies, that is, the former is ***more important than*** the latter?

> One way in which someone’s loyalty might be expressed is through a
> tendency to identify herself with the object of her loyalty. Such a
> loyal person to some extent treats the thing to which she is loyal as
> though it was her, feeling as she would feel and acting as she would
> act if certain things that are true of it were true of her. If your
> loyalty to your favorite sporting team is expressed in such a way,
> then you may feel like a success yourself when your team is doing
> well, and like a failure when your team is doing badly. You may feel
> pride when your team does something good — when it wins a tough game
> or raises money for charity — and you may feel shame when your team
> does something bad — when it gives a boring performance or mistreats
> its players. Such reactions ***exist beyond*** any tendencies to want
> to advance the interests of the object of your loyalty, to serve as
> its advocate, or to venerate it through involvement in appropriate
> rituals.

Answer (score 0):

Q. **What does 'exist beyond' mean in the passage?**

Does it mean 'such reactions exist in addition to any tendencies'? Or, such reactions precede any tendencies, that is, the former is more important than the latter?

---

**such reactions exist in addition to any tendencies** is probably somewhere close

**"it is not limited too"**

In this context it means **"it is not limited too"**, what would be considered normal and implies that the enthusiasm verges on the fanatical, where self and subject identity have merged. A common example is of a sports fan who feels that they are part of the club or in more extreme cases as if they are part of the team. Whilst clearly they are just a spectator.

**exist beyond**

**exist** verb [I] (BE)

**beyond** preposition, adverb (OUTSIDE A LIMIT)

Ref CED [**Exist**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exist)   [**Beyond**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/beyond)

Comment: Thank you, Brad.